# What is the formula used to produce a ftok() key?

Tags: c, linux, sysv-ipc, ftok

What is the formula used to produce a key that ftok() produces? ftok is a Linux function for creating keys for SYSTEM V IPC.

Comment: Read ftok manual page.

Comment: 1. Wouldn't that depend on which libc you're using?  2. Why do you care?

Comment: On Linux, most implementations of `libc` are free software. So study the source code of the particular `libc` you are using, probably [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) ore perhaps [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)

Comment: `ftok()` is not Linux-specific.  It is a standard part of the SysV IPC suite.

Comment: *ftok is a Linux function for creating keys for SYSTEM V IPC.*  And a horrible one at that.  Picking a random number and hoping it's unique, with no information on already-used keys on the system, is worse than picking a random number yourself.  At least you can actually collect information on what keys are already in use.

Answer (score 5):

In [ftok from glibc 2.29](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysvipc/ftok.c;h=e7c98ac29e1b0b20a239c4aced7ae8cf5f18ec70;hb=56c86f5dd516284558e106d04b92875d5b623b7a):

```
key_t
ftok (const char *pathname, int proj_id)
{
  struct stat64 st;
  key_t key;

  if (__xstat64 (_STAT_VER, pathname, &st) < 0)
    return (key_t) -1;

  key = ((st.st_ino & 0xffff) | ((st.st_dev & 0xff) << 16)
     | ((proj_id & 0xff) << 24));

  return key;
}
```

I.e. it's creating a 32-bit `key_t` by taking the upper 8 bits from the lower 8 bits of `proj_id`, the second upper 8 bits from the lower 8 bits of the device number of the provided `pathname`, and the lower 16 bits from the lower 16 bits of the inode number of the provided `pathname`.

[musl libc](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/ipc/ftok.c) uses the same algorithm:

```
key_t ftok(const char *path, int id)
{
    struct stat st;
    if (stat(path, &st) < 0) return -1;

    return ((st.st_ino & 0xffff) | ((st.st_dev & 0xff) << 16) | ((id & 0xffu) << 24));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ftok() source code in [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) library is :

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
key_t
ftok (const char *pathname, int proj_id)
{
  struct stat64 st;
  key_t key;
  if (__xstat64 (_STAT_VER, pathname, &st) < 0)
    return (key_t) -1;
  key = ((st.st_ino & 0xffff) | ((st.st_dev & 0xff) << 16)
         | ((proj_id & 0xff) << 24));
  return key;
}
```

Other functions are available [here](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysvipc/ftok.c.html) too.

Comment: What's the point of this answer? It just repeats what's in my answer (which is older by an hour) and links to a third-party site instead of the official glibc code repository.

Comment: I agree with melpomene. Please don't waste time bytes and internet band for useless things.